# Getting two many push notifications from google calendar api after an action

Tags: asp.net-web-api, google-calendar-api

I am developing an app that syncs with my google calendar with my database.
I Have everything running, but I have a problem.
Every time I do an action (add, delete, update) on my google calendar I receive multiple push notifications for the same event, and after a few events, I get blocked by Google services (403-user-rate-limit-exceeded).

to every notification i am answering with the proper status code, here is my code:

```
 [HttpPost, Route("notifications")]
 public HttpResponseMessage Notifications()
 {
      try
      {
          this.googleCalendarService.PerformEventsSync();
          var response = this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
          response.Content = new StringContent("200");
          return response;
      }
      catch (Exception e)
      {
         log.Error(e);
         return this.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
      }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so i found what was going on.

Turns out that while I was debugging and deploying my app I was creating multiple watch channels. 
What i did:

1. Created a variable to save my active channel id and it's expiration time
2. On each received notification I retrieve the header "X-Goog-Channel-ID"
3. Before preforming my sync I assure that its comming from the correct channel (my app can only have one channel)
4. When my expiration time is coming to an end I refresh my channel

Thank you